# Signed WPF app installed from signed MSIX still running from untrusted location

Tags: wpf, windows-10, uac, wap, msix

I have a valid code signing certificate. I use it to sign a WPF application. This app will run as an administrator. It has a valid app.manifest.

```
  <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
  </requestedPrivileges>
```

The MSIX file was built with the MSIX Packaging Tool. I signed the MSIX application package with the same certificate. The appx manifest has these capabilities.

```
<Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="allowElevation" />
</Capabilities>
```

I install the MSIX file on a Windows 10 Pro machine running version 1903. It installs correctly, and indicates that it's a trusted application. When I launch the app, I see the yellow warning, "this file is running from an untrusted location." I expect to see the blue UAC elevation warning because the application is signed.

I unpacked the MSIX file and verified that the EXE is signed with the code signing certificate. It is. I launched the EXE file and I see the correct, blue, UAC elevation warning with the company name from the certificate.

Why does Windows 10 think the WPF application is launching from an untrusted source?

Comment: I have an update for this issue. One of my machines received a Windows 10 Update to version 2004. Now the correct behavior is seen when I launch the app. So it must have been a bug in the earlier versions of Windows. It's too bad. I can't ship it as an MSIX package if customers are going to see that "untrusted location" warning.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are developing the app from scratch, you should use the Windows Application Packaging Project from Visual Studio to generate the package. The MSIX packaging tool is intended only for converting to MSIX apps for which you don't have the source code.

Stefan Wick from MSFT worked in thiw are and he wrote some very useful tutorials on the topic:
https://stefanwick.com/tag/allowelevation/

Ping me on Twitter (if he didn't noticed thies question yet), he might have more details.

My suspicion is that you get this warning because the app is sideloaded (i.e. not installed from the MS Store) and it is also using allowElevation.

Just for testing. Can you remove the allowElevation capability from the package and reinstall it, using the same certificate? (You will probably need to manually launch it as and admin, otherwise it will silently crash).

Comment: I use the Wndows Application Packaging Project in Visual Studio 2019. However, it has a number of issues. First, it doesn't take the files from the target directory of the application that is referenced. It rebuilds it's own. Second, it has a race condition and it doesn't wait for the application's post-build event to finish before it creates its own target directory with the results. The post build event signs the app but due to this race condition, it has to be added manually. That's why I use the MSIX Packaging Tool. I need to add the signed EXE to the package manually.